# Test remote image url with carrierwave using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave, factory-bot, stub

I want to speed up my spec tests for my remote image url upload using the carrierwave gem. In my model I will only allow an image upload by remote url not by upload. For testing the model I use FactoryGirl with the remote_image_url field and a placeholder image.

My tests run successful but it takes a lot of time to for each test (approx. 3-4 sec) because of downloading the image. I know I can stub my tests to avoid these external http requests but I do not have an idea how to do it with factory girl. Can anyone help?

Model:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, StoreUploader
  attr_accessible :name, :remote_image_url
  validates :remote_image_url, presence: true
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :store do
    name "Corner store"
    remote_image_url "http://placehold.it/800x600"
  end
end
```

RspecController:

```
describe Api::StoreController, type: :api do
  let!(:store) { create :store }

  before(:each) do
    get :show, id: store.id
  end

  it "returns a successful response" do
    expect(response).to be_success
  end

  it "each store has the correct fields" do
    expect(json).to match("name", "image")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use some public image in your dropbox, but if you want to have testing isolated and able to run offline then you can look at `gem "webmock"`.

Other option start rack web-app in parallel thread and serve image from there.

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'webrick'

module TestingPurposeServer
  def self.run!(port = nil)
    if port.nil?
      # ask system to pick free port for us
      server = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 0)
      port = server.addr[1]
      server.close
    end

    thread = Thread.new do
      begin
        options = { :Port => port, :BindAddress => '127.0.0.1', :AccessLog => [], :Logger => WEBrick::Log.new("/dev/null"), :OutputBufferSize => 5 } #WEBrick::Log::new("/dev/null") }

        server = ::WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(options)
        server.mount "/", Rack::Handler::WEBrick, VtDirectServer::Server
        server.start
      rescue Exception => e
        puts e.message
        puts e.backtrace
      end
    end

    # wait for opening port
    while port_open?('127.0.0.1', port, 1)
      sleep 0.01
    end
    sleep 0.1

    port
  end

  def self.port_open?(ip, port, seconds = 1)
    Timeout::timeout(seconds) do
      begin
        TCPSocket.new(ip, port).close
        true
      rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
        false
      end
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    false
  end

  class Server < ::Sinatra::Base
    # your sinatra app there
  end
end

port = TestingPurposeServer.run!

local_server_url = "http://127.0.0.1:#{port}/"
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the webmock gem. This is great and speeds up my test dramatically.